# AngularJS and JQuery not playing nice, ng-show not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a page with a jquery calendar and then some forms below it for some event submissions. All was fine until I decided to use angularjs for form validation.

The issue is that my error message p element never loses its display:none.

If I remove the jquery script declaration it works but the calendar is gone.

I have the script for jquery at the bottom so I moved it to the top but no difference.

Seems like there should be a simple fix to this but I'll be if I can figure it out.

Here is one of the form elements.

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="authorname" placeholder="Author Name" ng-model="book.authorname" ng-required="true">
  <p class="error" ng-show="authorname.$invalid && authorname.$touched">
    You must fill out your author name.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have found that the interference between jquery and angular is deeper than just the ng-show issues so I am removing angular altogether since the bulk of my site is jquery heavy.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

angular validation works in a form only. If you want to use the validation outside of a form you have to declare `ng-form` to the top container.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('Example', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = function(){}
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Example">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController" >
      <form name="bookForm">
        <input type="email" name="authorname" ng-model="book.authorname" ng-required="true" />
        <input type="text" ng-click="test()" placeholder="Test" />
        <p class="error" ng-show="bookForm.authorname.$invalid">
    You must fill out your author name.</p>
       </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Anthony C. All the elements are in form tags. I just added one element to show the code. there must be some interference from jquery. I did read something about jquery handling $http so angular updates are missed? Not sure about that though.

Comment: @TyB, so you have the form name in your actual ng-show statement?`ng-show="YourFormName.authorname.$invalid &&"`

Comment: No. I have the top level form tag and then multiple input elements. This is just one on them I used to show how the elements are coded.

Comment: @TyB, I think you need to give a name to the form element. Take a look at this tutorial. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation